# Finding specific values in a dictionary, Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
position={'Part1':('A23-1','A24-2','A24-4','A25-1','A27-5'),
          'Part2':('A26-7','B50-6','C1-3'),
          'Part3':('EM45-4','GU8-9','EM40-3','A15-2')}
```

So I have this dictionary, showing a "part" as the key and the value being the position in a warehouse. Now let's say I want to find which parts are on shelf A25 through A27, I've met a wall. So far I've come up with:

```
for part, pos in position:
    if str.split(pos)=='A25' or 'A26' or 'A27':
        print(part,'can be found on shelf A25-A27')
```

However, this gives me a ValueError, which I've found to be 'cause all of the values have different lengths, so how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think `str.split(pos)` is going to do, but probably not what you want.  :)

Similarly, `if foo == 1 or 2` doesn't check whether `foo` is either of those values; it's parsed as `(foo == 1) or 2`, which is always true because `2` is a true value.  You want `foo in (1, 2)`.

You're also trying to loop over `position` alone, which gives you only the keys; that's probably the source of your error.

The values in your dictionary are themselves tuples, so you need a second loop:

```
for part, positions in position.items():
    for pos in positions:
        if pos.split('-')[0] in ('A25', 'A26', 'A27'):
            print(part, "can be found on shelves A25 through A27")
            break
```

You could avoid the inner loop with an `any` as shown in the other answer, but imo that's hard to read with a complex condition like this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you’re trying to do:

```
>>> position={'Part1':('A23-1','A24-2','A24-4','A25-1','A27-5'),
...           'Part2':('A26-7','B50-6','C1-3'),
...           'Part3':('EM45-4','GU8-9','EM40-3','A15-2')}
>>> for part,pos in position.items():
...     if any(p.split('-',1)[0] in ["A%d" %i for i in range(25,28)] for p in pos):
...             print(part,'can be found on shelf A25-A27')
... 
Part1 can be found on shelf A25-A27
Part2 can be found on shelf A25-A27
```

But I’m going to suggest that you transform your data structure a little:

```
>>> positions = {}
>>> for item,poss in position.items():
...     for pos in poss:
...         shelf, col = pos.split('-')
...         if shelf not in positions:
...             positions[shelf] = {}
...         if col not in positions[shelf]:
...             positions[shelf][col] = []
...         positions[shelf][col].append(item)
...
```

Now you can do this:

```
>>> shelves = "A25 A26 A27".split()
>>> for shelf in shelves:
...     for col in positions[shelf]:
...         for item in positions[shelf][col]:
...             print(item, "is on shelf", shelf)
... 
Part1 is on shelf A25
Part2 is on shelf A26
Part1 is on shelf A27
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient one-line solution:

```
>>> position = {'Part1':('A23-1','A24-2','A24-4','A25-1','A27-5'),
...             'Part2':('A26-7','B50-6','C1-3'),
...             'Part3':('EM45-4','GU8-9','EM40-3','A15-2')}
>>> lst = [k for k,v in position.items() if any(x.split('-')[0] in ('A25', 'A26', 'A27') for x in v)]
>>> lst
['Part2', 'Part1']
>>>
>>> for x in sorted(lst):
...     print(x,'can be found on shelf A25-A27.')
...
Part1 can be found on shelf A25-A27.
Part2 can be found on shelf A25-A27.
>>>
```